# How to constrain tags between 3 tables

Tags: mysql, tags, constraints

I'm working on a tags system, what it should do is you can have a query and selected tags, e.g. `jquery` and tags of `javascript`, `library`. It should only show related scripts with the query AND only that have the tags. This is the database layout:

Scripts table:

```
+-----------+---------------+
| script_id | name          |
+-----------+---------------+
|         1 | jQuery        |
|         2 | Sencha Touch  |
|         3 | Codeigniter   |
|         4 | Google Chrome |
|         5 | memcached     |
|         6 | PHP           |
|         7 | MooTools      |
|         8 | node.js       |
|         9 | jQuery Mobile |
+-----------+---------------+
```

Tags table:

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+
| tag_id | name        | url_name    |
+--------+-------------+-------------+
|      1 | JavaScript  | javascript  |
|      2 | Library     | library     |
|      3 | PHP         | php         |
|      4 | MySQL       | mysql       |
|      5 | Cache       | cache       |
|      6 | HTML        | html        |
|      7 | Open source | open-source |
+--------+-------------+-------------+
```

Tagged table:

```
+-----------+--------+-----------+
| tagged_id | tag_id | script_id |
+-----------+--------+-----------+
|         1 |      1 |         1 |  # javascript -- jQuery
|         2 |      2 |         1 |  # library    -- jQuery
|         3 |      1 |         9 |  # javascript -- jQuery mobile
+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

When I run my SQL, it still picks up `jQuery Mobile` but it shouldn't because it doesn't contain the `library` tag where `jQuery` does, I need it to constrain results that must meet the tags selected.

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT scripts.script_id,
       scripts.name
FROM
(
    scripts scripts

    LEFT OUTER JOIN tagged tagged ON tagged.script_id = scripts.script_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN tags tags ON tags.tag_id = tagged.tag_id
)
WHERE MATCH(scripts.name) AGAINST ('jquery*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND ( tags.url_name = 'javascript' OR tags.url_name = 'library' )
GROUP BY script_id
ORDER BY scripts.name
LIMIT 0, 25
```

It returns:

```
+-----------+---------------+
| script_id | name          |
+-----------+---------------+
|         1 | jQuery        |
|         9 | jQuery Mobile |
+-----------+---------------+
```

If I change `OR` to `AND`, it won't return anything at all or if I remove the brackets from the tags `(` and `)`, it won't return anything too.

How do I make the query constrain the tags?

Comment: Have you tried `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: But not all scripts are tagged.

Comment: The results look ok. You're asking for scripts that match "jQuery" and match tag url of either "javascript" or "library". This is what the results are. btw there's no need to alias a table with an alias that is the same as the table name ("SELECT [...] FROM scripts scripts"); you can omit the alias. You only need the alias of you want to shorten the table name or you're referencing the same table more than once.

Comment: Have a look at these tagging solutions: http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html
http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/06/tagsystems-performance-tests.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
select s.script_id, s.name from scripts s
join tagged tj on s.script_id = tj.script_id
join tags t on t.tag_id = tj.tag_id
where s.name like 'jQuery%' and t.url_name in ('javascript', 'library')
group by s.script_id, s.name
having count(*) = 2
order by s.name
limit 25
```

The only consideration with this is that the `2` must be replaced with the amount of elements in the `in` clause.

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c24c/1).

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your solution is that it creates multiple row when joined together, but each row has only one tag value. If you use the OR condition, then any of the matched tag is enough to return. With an AND no row can have two different value.

Until you group them together, three separate row is generated:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|     tag_id| script_id | name          |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|         1 |         1 | jQuery        |
|         2 |         1 | jQuery        |
|         1 |         9 | jQuery Mobile |
+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

To solve this, you have to use the OR condition, but after the group, use

```
HAVING count(tag_id) = 2
```

This tells the sql, to evaluate each group based on how many tags they have, and leave only those which have exactly 2 tags.

So the solution based on your code:

```
SELECT scripts.script_id,
       scripts.name
FROM
(
    scripts scripts

    LEFT OUTER JOIN tagged tagged ON tagged.script_id = scripts.script_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN tags tags ON tags.tag_id = tagged.tag_id
)
WHERE MATCH(scripts.name) AGAINST ('jquery*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND ( tags.url_name = 'javascript' OR tags.url_name = 'library' )
GROUP BY script_id
HAVING count(tag_id) = 2
ORDER BY scripts.name
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.script_id,
       s.name
FROM
        scripts AS s
    INNER JOIN 
        tagged AS st1
      ON  st1.script_id = s.script_id
    INNER JOIN tags AS tag1
      ON  tag1.tag_id = st1.tag_id
      AND tag1.url_name = 'javascript'
    INNER JOIN 
        tagged AS st2
      ON  st2.script_id = s.script_id
    INNER JOIN tags AS tag2
      ON  tag2.tag_id = st2.tag_id
      AND tag2.url_name = 'library'
ORDER BY s.name
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt:

```
SELECT s.script_id, s.name, so_tags.url_name 
  FROM so_scripts s 
       LEFT JOIN so_tagged USING (script_id) 
       LEFT JOIN so_tags USING (tag_id)
  WHERE s.script_id IN 
  (
    SELECT td.script_id FROM so_tagged td 
      LEFT JOIN so_tags t USING (tag_id) 
    WHERE t.url_name = "javascript" OR t.url_name = "library"
  ) 
GROUP BY url_name HAVING COUNT(s.name) = 2
```

It's a bit of a hack, it first looks for all entries matching any of the tags, then groups by name and returns only ones those entries who have number of matches equal to number of tags supplied :)

Not sure how fast it would be for 3, 4 or more tags, but at least it works :)